# Complex PDO query returns results on only some parts of query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm generating a query based on selected form parameters using PDO & prepared statements. I detect which values are present and then generate the appropriate PDO sub-statement, and then join them together by imploding the array of sub-statements with 'AND' in between. The queries work fine individually and in some combinations, but many combinations are getting the results for only part of the query - I've confirmed that everything is going ok with making the statement and binding parameters, but somehow it's simply ignoring part of the query. Here's some examples and what I'm getting back:

```
SELECT * FROM songtable WHERE (ENERGY BETWEEN :energy_from AND :energy_to) AND (GENRE = :genre OR GENRE2 = :genre OR GENRE3 = :genre) ORDER BY ARTIST ASC LIMIT 0, 7
```

Data returned: The genre search is performed correctly, energy entirely ignored. Remove the genre, the energy search works and vice-versa.

```
SELECT * FROM songtable WHERE (ENERGY BETWEEN :energy_from AND :energy_to) AND BANGER = :banger ORDER BY ARTIST ASC LIMIT 0, 7
```

Data returned: Correctly finds 'bangers' entirely ignores energy, remove either and they work normally.

```
SELECT * FROM songtable WHERE BANGER = :banger AND (GENRE = :genre OR GENRE2 = :genre OR GENRE3 = :genre) ORDER BY ARTIST ASC LIMIT 0, 7
```

Data returned: Finds correct genre and ignores banger. Again, remove either and they work normally.

All the queries work fine in phpmyadmin - and the problems seem to only occur when multiple conditions are grouped together - but some groupings return the desired results.... am I missing something about how PDO works? Should I not be using PDO?

Full relevant source:

```
function query($link, $query, $params) {
    echo $query;
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    if(count($params->getValues()) > 0) {
        foreach($params->getValues() as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindParam($key, $value); 
    }
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}

function getFilter($selection, $params, $sorting, $page) {
    $link = createLink('songs');
    $selection = "ID, ARTIST, GENRE, GENRE2, GENRE3, TITLE, WARMUP, PEAK, BANGER, FLOORFILLER, SONGKEY, ENERGY, BPM, TRACKURL, DATETIME, FILENAME";
    if($link != null) {
        $query = makeQuery("SELECT", $selection, $params, $sorting, $page);
        $result = query($link, $query, $params);
    }
    return $result->fetchAll();
}

function makeQuery($operation, $selection, $params, $sorting, $page) {
    return $operation . " " . $selection . " FROM songtable " . $params . $sorting . $page;
}

class FormParams  {
    private $query;
    private $values;
    private $sorting;
    private $page;
    private $user;

    //takes all existing arguments and fills
    public function __construct($data = array()) {
        if($this->valid('energy_from', $data) && $this->valid('energy_to', $data)) {
            $this->values[':energy_from'] = $data['energy_from'];
            $this->query[] = "(ENERGY BETWEEN :energy_from AND " . $data['energy_to'] . ")";
        } else if($this->valid('energy_from', $data)) {
            $this->values[':energy_from'] = $data['energy_from'];
            $this->query[] = "(ENERGY BETWEEN :energy_from AND 10)";
        } else if($this->valid('energy_to', $data)) {
            $this->query[] = "(ENERGY BETWEEN 1 AND " . $data['energy_to'] . ")";
        }
        if($this->valid('bpm_from', $data) && $this->valid('bpm_to', $data)) {
            $this->values[':bpm_from'] = $data['bpm_from'];
            $this->values[':bpm_to'] = $data['bpm_to'];
            $this->query['bpm_from'] = "(BPM BETWEEN :bpm_from AND " . $data['bpm_to'] . ")";
        } else if($this->valid('bpm_from', $data)) {
            $this->values[':bpm_from'] = $data['bpm_from'];
            $this->query['bpm_from'] = "(BPM BETWEEN :bpm_from AND 200)";
        } else if($this->valid('bpm_to', $data)) {
            $this->values[':bpm_to'] = $data['bpm_to'];
            $this->query[] = "(BPM BETWEEN 60 AND " . $data['bpm_to'] . ")";
        }
        if($this->valid('key_from', $data)) {
            $this->values[':key_from'] = $data['key_from'];
            $this->query['key_from'] = "KEY > :key_from";
        }
        if($this->valid('key_to', $data)) {
            $this->values[':key_to'] = $data['key_to'];
            $this->query[] = "KEY < :key_to";
        }
        if($data['set_placement'] == 1) {
            $this->values[':warmup'] = "1";
            $this->query[] = "WARMUP = :warmup";
        }
        else if($data['set_placement'] == 2) {
            $this->values[':peak'] = "1";
            $this->query[] = "PEAK = :peak";
        }
        if(array_key_exists('banger', $data)) {
            $this->values[':banger'] = "1";
            $this->query[] = "BANGER = :banger";
        }
        if(array_key_exists('floorfiller', $data)) {
            $this->values[':floorfiller'] = "1";
            $this->query[] = "FLOORFILLER = :floorfiller";
        }
        if($this->valid('genre', $data)) {
            if($data['genre'] == '1') {
                $this->values[':genre'] = 'Bass';
            } else if($data['genre'] == '2') {
                $this->values[':genre'] = 'House';
            } else if($data['genre'] == '3') {
                $this->values[':genre'] = 'Juke';
            } else if($data['genre'] == '4') {
                $this->values[':genre'] = 'B more';
            } else if($data['genre'] == '5') {
                $this->values[':genre'] = 'Trap';
            } else if($data['genre'] == '6') {
                $this->values[':genre'] = 'Twerk';
            } 
            $this->query[] = "(GENRE = :genre OR GENRE2 = :genre OR GENRE3 = :genre)";
        }
        if($this->valid('artist', $data)) {
            $this->values[':artist'] = $data['artist'];
            $this->query[] = "ARTIST = :artist";
        }
        if($this->valid('title', $data)) {
            $this->values[':title'] = $data['title'];
            $this->query[] = "TITLE = :title";
        }
        if($this->valid('column', $data) && $this->valid('order', $data)) {
            $this->sorting = new Sorting($data['column'], $data['order']);
        } else {
            //default sort - change to whatever youd like to initially load.
            $this->sorting = new Sorting("ARTIST", "ASC");
        }
        if($this->valid('page', $data)) {
            $this->page = new Page($data['page'], "7", null);
        } else {
            //default page - assume first page with default settings
            $this->page = new Page("1", "7", null);
        }
        if($this->valid('user', $data)) {
            $this->user = $data['user'];
        }

        //implement filtername?
        unset($data);
    }

    /*public function getSorting(){
        return $this->sorting;
    } */


    public function getPage(){
        return $this->page;
    }

    public function getUser(){
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getSort(){
        return $this->sorting;
    }

    public function setPageTotal($total) {
        $this->page->setTotal($total);
    }
    public function valid($key, $array) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            if($array[$key] != "" && $array[$key] != "0") {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getValues() {
        return $this->values;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (count($this->query) > 0) ? "WHERE " . implode("\r\n AND ", $this->query) : "";
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you provide the source code where you are using PDO?

Comment: yes there's a bit much relevant, think this is everything